# X-Loader Makefile explanation

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I was going through the Makefile of X-Loader for craneboard. We'll have to cross compile it for ARM. I was stuck at the following code and couldn't proceed. Kindly guide me in what has been done.

```
x-load: $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(LDSCRIPT)
        UNDEF_SYM=`$(OBJDUMP) -x $(LIBS) |sed  -n -e 's/.*\(__u_boot_cmd_.*\)/-u\1/p'|sort|uniq`;\
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $$UNDEF_SYM $(OBJS) \
            --start-group $(LIBS) --end-group $(PLATFORM_LIBS) \
            -Map x-load.map -o x-load

System.map: x-load
        @$(NM) $< | \
        grep -v '\(compiled\)\|\(\.o$$\)\|\( [aUw] \)\|\(\.\.ng$$\)\|\(LASH[RL]DI\)' | \
        sort > System.map

oneboot:    x-load.bin
        scripts/mkoneboot.sh
```

where,

```
OBJS  = cpu/$(CPU)/start.o

LIBS is a set of library archives

PLATFORM_LIBS is GCC Library

LD  = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld

LDFLAGS are the corresponding flags
```

Also, what is the need for `oneboot`? The `mkoneboot.sh` converts `x-load.bin.ift` to `x-load-signed.ift`. In what scenario, this will be used instead of the usual `x-load.bin.ift`?

The `System.map` is used for the debugging purpose. What is the need for `x-load.map`?